# Import MS ACCESS Database tables into teradata

Tags: ms-access-2010, teradata

I am trying to import MS ACCESS Database tables into Teradata 13.0 using automated script. Basically a job which will import all tables from MS-ACCESS to related tables in Teradata. I searched on internet but no luck. So lease let me know if its possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

export each table to csv file .

Import that file to Teradata using any one of its utilities ( ex : fastload or sql assistant ).

Or with TPT you can connect to Ms access via odbc and load to Teradata.

you can check manuals.